# Take two numbers to one number

Tags: c, math

I have two int values that I want to combine into a decimal number. So for example, I have A = 1234 and B = 323444. Both are int and I do not want to change it if possible.

I want to combine them to get 1234234233.323444.

My initial method was to divide b by 1e6 and add it to A to get my value.
I assigned

```
int A = 1234234233;
int B = 323444;
double C;

A = 1234;
B = 323444;
C = A + (B/ 1000000);

printf("%.6f\n", C);
```

I get 1234234233.000000 as a result. It rounds my C and I do not want that as I want 1234234233.323444

how can I solve this?

Comment: It is impossible to get exactly 1234234233.323444 because that value is not exactly representable in the floating-point format most C implementations use. When you attempt it, you will get a slightly different value. If you write code to extract the original values from the “combined” value, you must allow for these differences.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Maybe yes. But the everyday interpretation of "to round" is what's taught in elementary school, i. e. convert to the closest integer (yielding the greater integer for halves). As far as I know, C99 explicitly requires implicit floating-point to integral conversions to *truncate,* which is what is called "round towards zero", if I'm right. Nevertheless, I don't like calling truncation "rounding" because that just causes confusion. If I want to be explicit and precise, I will just use one of the more descriptive names (the ones you enumerated too) anyway.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I did not rebuke OP - your scoff is unwarranted. Indeed you are correct in that "rounding" is ambiguous as-is when referring to IEEE-754 rounding modes, as it does not refer to one method but a family of operations. However, just out of curiosity, I've looked up the paper of the IEEE 754 standard, and in section 4.1 it says that "An implementation of this standard shall provide round to nearest as the default rounding mode" - so even though it uses the word "rounding" to the set of operations described in there, the default behavior is still rounding to the nearest number.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I deleted it to avoid extending this discussion further, I don't think it does any good for this post. It is true that the default behavior wasn't selected for its name, but it's also true that there is a straightforward, strong relation between it being the default choice and "rounding" being the usual name for "round towards nearest" - as you mentioned, this method has reasonable, good and intuitive numerical properties, and that's why it's both used in IEEE-754 and taught in school; this is not a coincidence. I understand that you are an expert in this field, but...

Comment: @EricPostpischil ...you can understand that sometimes other people get things right as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
C = A + (B/ 1000000.0);
```

ie, make the denominator as double so that when integer by integer division is made it does not return weird results like you are getting.

**NOTE:-**

- Integer/Integer = Integer
- Integer/Double = Double
- Double/Integer = Double
- Double/Double = Double

Comment: This actually does not produce the exact result the OP requests since 1234234233.323444 is not exactly representable in the floating-point format most C implementations use. When the OP attempts to extract the original numbers, they are likely to get incorrect answers in many cases.

Answer (score 2):

`B` is an integer and dividing an integer by another integer (`10000` here) will always give an integer and that's why you are getting unexpected result. Changing `10000`, which is of type `int`, to `10000.0` (`double` type) will solve this problem. It seem that `10000` and `10000.0`  are integer by mathematical definition but both are of different type in programming languages, former is of type `int` while latter is of type `double`.

```
C = A + (B/ 1000000.0);
```

or

```
C = A + ((double)B/ 1000000);
```

to get the expected result.

Comment: @EricPostpischil; I think `10000.0` has type float but after promotion it becomes `double` type, Isn't it?